# How can I root my General Mobile e-Tab 7b tablet?

Tags: rooting

How can I root the General Mobile e-Tab 7b tablet? It's currently running Android 4.1.1, kernel version 3.0.8.

Comment: Can you provide a few more details on your device? I never heard of that. Maybe there's a link to its specs you can give? At least the Android version running would be helpful. Is it [this one](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/General-Mobile-e-tab-32GB_id6744), running Android 2.3? // You might also want to take a look at the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for some general ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy root access and Developer support, It would be a good idea to get a well known android device from the likes of Samsung/HTC/Sony, etc.

I don't think there is good support for niche and low volume tablets.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

EDIT:
You can do something like this:

Look up the ODM of your Tablet. It probably is some Chinese no-label company.
See other tablets which are based on it and check if you could root them.

Comment: How can I know ODM of my Tablet

Comment: Alok, "buy another device" is not quite an answer on how to root an existing device ;)

Comment: @forsubhi, I would have suggested Google. I tried that myself and found out that This question was the link at the top, so the chances of finding anything important there are slim.
It could help if you could specify some details about it, say the processor(I need the specific processor OEM and model number eg: Exynos 4410 or AllWinner A13, etc.) and the OS it is running. Maybe We could figure something out.

Comment: @Izzy, true. Should Have thought about that earlier. Sorry :). I'm kinda new here.

Comment: model number g08refem667

Comment: android system = android 4.1.1

Comment: kernal version = 3.0.8